# Scroll indicator is not visible in collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I trie to make MessagesCollectionView like bubble boxes and some text in it. So I tried to make scroll indicator visible by

```
  collectionView?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
```

option, but it seems not working for my case cause maybe there is insufficient cells
[image]

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    collectionView?.register(ChatLogMessageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true

    collectionView?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true


   collectionView?.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 0,bottom: (tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height)!,right: 0)

}
```

Can I make scroll indicator visible even with less than that amount of cells? If it possible, please, give me a clue.

Comment: if there is no scrolling, there is no sense in showing an indicator.. why would you even want that?

Comment: I wanted it because in tutorial video https://youtu.be/p8IaS5lmhuM?t=2m31s i just mentioned this moment he already has the same collectionView with the same messages with the same simulator but he has indicator bar but i am not((((

Comment: Which iPhone simulator are you using? He is using a iPhone 6s. The device resolution is of course also one aspect of fitting the content to the screen.

Comment: absolutely the same

Answer (score 0):

Scroll indicator is shown only when the content of the `scrollView` is larger that the `scrollView` itself. If the content does not extend the area of the `scrollView` the scroll indicator is not supposed to be presented - that's the intended behavior, because there is no sense at all for the scroll indicator to be presented in such case.

In the video link you added the cells are obviously larger than the `tableView` can present at once - therefore scroll indicator is presented. In your screenshot all the cells are obviously fitting the `tableView` without scrolling - therefore not indicator is shown, and it should NOT be shown.

The most you can do is set:

```
collectionView?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
```

And then just leave the `collectionView` to take care of when to show indicator and when not - that's the best approach, because that assures the scroll indicator will have standard behavior, and no weird anomalies would occur (like in your case - showing an indicator when there is no space to scroll is something that I would really not like to see in an app).